# xarray - how to rename dimensions on a DataArray object

Tags: python-xarray

I have a DataArray object named rio.

```
In [59]: rio
Out[59]: 
<xarray.DataArray (band: 1, y: 106, x: 193)>
array([[[0, 0, ..., 0, 0],
        [0, 0, ..., 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, ..., 0, 0],
        [0, 0, ..., 0, 0]]], dtype=uint8)
Coordinates:
  * band     (band) int32 1
  * y        (y) float64 -33.9 -33.95 -34.0 -34.05 ... -39.05 -39.1 -39.15 -39.2
  * x        (x) float64 140.8 140.8 140.9 140.9 ... 149.9 149.9 150.0 150.0
Attributes:
    transform:   (0.04791259799999997, 0.0, 140.776046753, 0.0, -0.0504760740...
    crs:         +init=epsg:4326
    res:         (0.04791259799999997, 0.05047607400000004)
    is_tiled:    1
    nodatavals:  (255.0,)
```

I would like to rename y to latitude and x to longitude. So the resulted rio object will be:

```
In [59]: rio
Out[59]: 
<xarray.DataArray (band: 1, latitude: 106, longitude: 193)>
array([[[0, 0, ..., 0, 0],
        [0, 0, ..., 0, 0],
        ...,
        [0, 0, ..., 0, 0],
        [0, 0, ..., 0, 0]]], dtype=uint8)
Coordinates:
  * band     (band) int32 1
  * latitude         (latitude) float64 -33.9 -33.95 -34.0 -34.05 ... -39.05 -39.1 -39.15 -39.2
  * longitude        (longitude) float64 140.8 140.8 140.9 140.9 ... 149.9 149.9 150.0 150.0
Attributes:
    transform:   (0.04791259799999997, 0.0, 140.776046753, 0.0, -0.0504760740...
    crs:         +init=epsg:4326
    res:         (0.04791259799999997, 0.05047607400000004)
    is_tiled:    1
    nodatavals:  (255.0,)
```

I need help on what methods I should use on the DataArray class?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
   rio = rio.rename({'x': 'longitude','y': 'latitude'})
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to the answer for others coming here from google. When you rename the dimensions, there's a new DataArray returned. And you have to assign that back to the old name. Meaning you should do
`rio = rio.rename({'x': 'longitude','y': 'latitude'})`. That wasn't obvious to me, just renaming it isn't enough.